# Usin bun in docker. Cant locate postcss config file

Tags: docker, vite, postcss, bun

I am trying to use bun instead of npm in docker. I have bun [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/oven/bun) but when I try to build inside a container an error shows that it can not find postcss config. I have my package.json set to module and I have postcss.config.cjs in root folder.

```
#9 0.415 $ bunx --bun vite build                                                                                                                                 
#9 0.895 vite v4.4.9 building for production...                                                                                                                  
#9 0.913 Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /tmp/frontend): [EBADF] Bad file descriptor                                   
#9 0.913 undefined
#9 0.913    code: "EBADF"
#9 0.913  syscall: "fstat"
#9 0.913    errno: -9
#9 0.913 
#9 0.913 Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /tmp/frontend): [EBADF] Bad file descriptor
#9 0.913 undefined
#9 0.913    code: "EBADF"
#9 0.913  syscall: "fstat"
#9 0.913    errno: -9
#9 0.913 
#9 0.913 Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /tmp/frontend): [EBADF] Bad file descriptor
#9 0.913 undefined
#9 0.913    code: "EBADF"
#9 0.913  syscall: "fstat"
#9 0.913    errno: -9
#9 0.913 
#9 0.913 Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /tmp/frontend): [EBADF] Bad file descriptor
#9 0.913 undefined
#9 0.913    code: "EBADF"
#9 0.913  syscall: "fstat"
#9 0.913    errno: -9
#9 0.913 
#9 0.938 transforming...
#9 1.075 ✓ 6 modules transformed.
#9 1.075 ✓ built in 178ms
#9 1.075 [vite:css] Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /tmp/frontend): [EBADF] Bad file descriptor
#9 1.075 undefined
#9 1.075 file: /tmp/frontend/src/css/tables.css
#9 1.075 error during build:
#9 1.075 
#9 1.114 error: "vite" exited with code 1 (SIGHUP)
#9 1.115 error: script "build" exited with code 1 (SIGHUP)
```

When I try it outside docker the build finishes.

Comment: I am getting the same "Failed to load PostCSS config message", only in the docker container. I use the oven/bun:latest with arm64. Previously I used tailwindcss, but ripped it out and still have the PostCSS error.

Comment: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/4723

I have found this. But still this issue wasnt resolved.